# Passing the procedure name dynamically into another procedure with both the procedure having ref_cursor as out parameter

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE PROCEDURENEW
(pi_procname varchar2,
PO_CURSOR    OUT sys_refcursor)
IS
    P_RS            sys_refcursor;
    L_COLS          NUMBER;
    L_DESC DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
    L_CURS          INTEGER;
    L_VARCHAR       VARCHAR2(400);
    out_result      VARCHAR2(600);
    out_result1     VARCHAR2(400);
    v_sql           varchar2(300);
    out_result2     varchar2(300);
    v_sql1           varchar2(300);
BEGIN
    -- //These two lines are showing an error.
    v_sql1 := 'SELECT'||pi_procname||'from dual';
    execute immediate 'begin'||v_sql1||'(P_RS);end;' USING P_RS;
    -- //These above two lines are showing an error.

    L_CURS := DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(P_RS);
    DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(
      C => L_CURS, COL_CNT => L_COLS,
      DESC_T => L_DESC);

      FOR i IN 1..L_COLS LOOP
       DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(L_CURS, i, L_VARCHAR, 4000);
      END LOOP;        

      FOR i IN 1..L_COLS LOOP
        IF(
          L_DESC(i).col_name = 'CREATEDBY' OR L_DESC(i).col_name = 'CREATEDDT' OR
          L_DESC(i).col_name = 'CREATEDAT' OR L_DESC(i).col_name = 'UPDATEDBY' OR
          L_DESC(i).col_name = 'UPDATEDDT' OR L_DESC(i).col_name = 'UPDATEDAT' OR
          L_DESC(i).col_name = 'ROWVERSION'
        ) THEN
          DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(L_CURS, i, L_VARCHAR);
          L_VARCHAR := NULL;
        ELSE
          out_result := out_result||
          CASE
          WHEN i = 1 THEN
            NULL
          ELSE
            ','
          END || L_DESC(i).col_name;
        END IF;
      END LOOP;

      WHILE DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(L_CURS) > 0 LOOP
        FOR i IN 1..L_COLS LOOP
          IF(
            L_DESC(i).col_name = 'CREATEDBY' or L_DESC(i).col_name = 'CREATEDDT' or
            L_DESC(i).col_name = 'CREATEDAT' or L_DESC(i).col_name = 'UPDATEDBY' or
            L_DESC(i).col_name = 'UPDATEDDT' or L_DESC(i).col_name = 'UPDATEDAT' or
            L_DESC(i).col_name = 'ROWVERSION'
            )
          THEN
            DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(L_CURS, i, L_VARCHAR);
            L_VARCHAR := NULL;
          ELSE
            DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(L_CURS, i, L_VARCHAR);
            out_result1 := out_result1|| CHR(10) ||L_VARCHAR ;         
          END IF;
        END LOOP;
      END LOOP;

      out_result2 := out_result ||chr(10)|| out_result1;
      DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(L_CURS);

      OPEN PO_CURSOR for select out_result2 from dual; 
END PROCEDURENEW;
```

I want the procedure name to be passed to the database dynamically from the ui and display the result in the grid.
And I tried to write a procedure which takes the procedure name as input and execute the procedure, and pass the result as `REF_CURSOR`.
The procedures which are to be executed also return result in ref cursor.
But when the above proc is compiled then I am facing a lot of errors.
I want to know the way of calling the procedure name inside the above procedure.

Comment: What is your Oracle version?

Comment: My version is Oracle 11g

Answer (score 1):

Is should be like this

```
execute immediate 'begin '||pi_procname||'(:P_RS);end;' USING OUT P_RS;
```

Note the space character after the 'begin'!

Comment: Is it require to give colon before the ref_cursor i.e (:P_RS)?

Comment: Yes, that's required, otherwise Oracle try to interpred as column name and will fail.